# How to return an variable from a AsyncTask class to an fragment

Tags: android, class, android-fragments, android-asynctask, code-reuse

I have created an multiple fragments which all require data from an server. So I created an reusable `AsyncTask`. Which connects to an server via sockets, transfers some packets and finaly receives the response. How can I 'dynamically' return the `result` (a.k.a the response) from `onPostExecute`? I have created an flowchart to explain myself better.

[image: How to return an variable from a AsyncTask class to an fragment flowchat]

Comment: Extend your`AsyncTask` and then pass a listener to it. Once onPostExecute if finished call that listener. Or alternatively use an event bus. http://square.github.io/otto/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AsyncTask` can simply call a callback in the provided `Fragment` in `onPostExecute`, or the `AsyncTask` can be a nested class of the given fragment.

for example

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    void onResult(Result result) {...}

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Result> {
        doInBackground(...) {}
        onPostExecute(Result result)  {
            onResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

This has the drawbacks of holding the reference of the fragment until your task is complete. If your task always terminates eventually and is not referenced by any static context, then it's fine since the memory will eventually be collected.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a listener, which is implemented in every fragment using the async task. Define a method in the interface with the required result parameters.
You can pass the reference to the async task and store it there in a [weak reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html%20weak%20reference)